# Not able to insert in second table (Transaction) in android sqlite

Tags: sqliteopenhelper

I have two tables, category and transaction. I have single SQLiteOpenHelper class and two classes to insert and retrieve category and transaction. But I am not able to insert in transaction table. Getting negative number while inserting.

DatabaseHelper Class

```
package com.mm.bipin.mm;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String DATABASE_NAME="mm";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;

public static final String CATEGORY_TABLE_NAME="category";
public static final String CATEGORY_CID="_id";
public static final String CATEGORY_TITLE= "title";
public static final String CATEGORY_DATE="date";
public static final String CATEGORY_TYPE="type";
public static final String CATEGORY_NOTE="note";
private static final String CATEGORY_CREATE_TABLE= "CREATE TABLE "+CATEGORY_TABLE_NAME+" ( "+CATEGORY_CID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
        "  "+CATEGORY_TITLE+" VARCHAR(255), "+CATEGORY_DATE+" VARCHAR(255),"+CATEGORY_TYPE+" INTEGER,"+CATEGORY_NOTE+" VARCHAR(255) )";
private static final String CATEGORY_DROP_TABLE=
        " DROP TABLE IF EXISTS  " +CATEGORY_TABLE_NAME;


public static final String TRANSACTION_TABLE_NAME="transaction";
public static final String TRANSACTION_TID="_id";
public static final String TRANSACTION_CATEGORY_ID="category_id";
public static final String TRANSACTION_TITLE="title";
public static final String TRANSACTION_AMOUNT="amount";
public static final String TRANSACTION_DATE="date";
public static final String TRANSACTION_NOTE="note";


private static final String TRANSACTION_CREATE_TABLE= "CREATE TABLE "+TRANSACTION_TABLE_NAME+" " +
        " ("+TRANSACTION_TID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,   " +
        "  "+TRANSACTION_CATEGORY_ID+" INTEGER ,  " +
        "  "+TRANSACTION_TITLE+" VARCHAR(255) ,  " +
        "  "+TRANSACTION_AMOUNT+" VARCHAR(255)     ,  " +
        " "+TRANSACTION_DATE+" VARCHAR(255)   ,  " +
        " "+TRANSACTION_NOTE+" VARCHAR(255) ) ";

private static final String TRANSACTION_DROP_TABLE=
        " DROP TABLE IF EXISTS  " +TRANSACTION_TABLE_NAME;

private Context context;
public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.context=context;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    try {
        //getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL(CATEGORY_CREATE_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(TRANSACTION_CREATE_TABLE);
        Message.message(context, "DB created");
    }
    catch(android.database.SQLException e){
        Message.message(context," "+e);
    }
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    try{
        db.execSQL(CATEGORY_DROP_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(TRANSACTION_DROP_TABLE);
        Message.message(context,"DB dropped");
    }
    catch(android.database.SQLException e){
        Message.message(context," "+e);
    }
}
}
```

CategoryDatabaseAdapter class

```
package com.mm.bipin.mm.category;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.mm.bipin.mm.Category;
import com.mm.bipin.mm.DatabaseHelper;
import com.mm.bipin.mm.Message;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class CategoryDatabaseAdapter {
DatabaseHelper helper;
SQLiteDatabase db;
public static String[] columns={DatabaseHelper.CATEGORY_TITLE,DatabaseHelper.CATEGORY_DATE,DatabaseHelper.CATEGORY_NOTE};
public CategoryDatabaseAdapter(Context context){
    helper=new DatabaseHelper(context);
}
Context context;
public long insertCategory(String title,int year,int month,int day,int type,String note){
    db=helper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.CATEGORY_TITLE,title);
    String date= convertDateToString(year, month, day);
    contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.CATEGORY_DATE,date);
    contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.CATEGORY_TYPE,type);
    contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.CATEGORY_NOTE,note);
    long id=db.insert(DatabaseHelper.CATEGORY_TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);

    return id;
}



public Cursor getAllRows(){
    db=helper.getWritableDatabase();
    String[] columns={DatabaseHelper.CATEGORY_CID,DatabaseHelper.CATEGORY_TITLE,DatabaseHelper.CATEGORY_DATE,
            DatabaseHelper.CATEGORY_TYPE,DatabaseHelper.CATEGORY_NOTE};
    Cursor mCursor=db.query(DatabaseHelper.CATEGORY_TABLE_NAME,columns,null,null,null,null,null);
    if(mCursor!=null){
        mCursor.moveToNext();
    }

    return mCursor;

}

public String convertDateToString(int year,int month,int day){
    StringBuilder str=new StringBuilder();
    str.append(year);
    str.append("-");
    str.append(month);
    str.append("-");
    str.append(day);
    return str.toString();
}
}
```

TransactionDatabaseAdapter class

```
package com.mm.bipin.mm.transaction;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.DatabaseUtils;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.mm.bipin.mm.DatabaseHelper;
import com.mm.bipin.mm.Message;
import com.mm.bipin.mm.category.CategoryDatabaseAdapter;


public class TransactionDatabaseAdapter {
DatabaseHelper helper;
SQLiteDatabase db;

public static String[] columns=    {DatabaseHelper.TRANSACTION_TITLE,DatabaseHelper.TRANSACTION_DATE,
    DatabaseHelper.TRANSACTION_NOTE};
 TransactionDatabaseAdapter(Context context){
    helper=new DatabaseHelper(context);
}

public long insertTransaction(String title,int category_id ,String amount,int year,int month,int day,String note){
    //SQLiteDatabase db=helper.getWritableDatabase();

    db=helper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.TRANSACTION_CATEGORY_ID,category_id);
    contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.TRANSACTION_TITLE,title);
    contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.TRANSACTION_AMOUNT,amount);

    String date= convertDateToString(year, month, day);
    contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.TRANSACTION_DATE,date);
    contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.TRANSACTION_NOTE,note);
    long id=db.insert(DatabaseHelper.TRANSACTION_TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
    return id;
}
public String convertDateToString(int year,int month,int day){
    StringBuilder str=new StringBuilder();
    str.append(year);
    str.append("-");
    str.append(month);
    str.append("-");
    str.append(day);
    return str.toString();
}
public Cursor getAllTransaction(){
    db=helper.getWritableDatabase();
    String[] transactionColumns={DatabaseHelper.TRANSACTION_TID,DatabaseHelper.TRANSACTION_CATEGORY_ID, DatabaseHelper.TRANSACTION_TITLE,
            DatabaseHelper.TRANSACTION_AMOUNT,DatabaseHelper.TRANSACTION_DATE,DatabaseHelper.TRANSACTION_NOTE};
    Cursor mCursor=db.query(DatabaseHelper.TRANSACTION_TABLE_NAME,transactionColumns,null,null,null,null,null);
    if(mCursor!=null) mCursor.moveToNext();

    return mCursor;
}
}
```

These are my three classes of database functions. insertTransaction() is returning negative value which means data are not being inserted.

There might be problem due openhelper conflict. But I dont know how and where. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Use `insertOrThrow` to get an error message.

Comment: I found that I am getting error in SQLException e while creating table 'transaction'. error statement is:    android.database.sqlite.SQLException: near "transaction": syntax error (code 1):, while compiling: CREATE TABLE transaction(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, category_id INTEGER, title VARCHAR(255), amount VARCHAR(255), date VARCHAR(255), note VARCHAR(255))

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself. I had created table name 'transaction' which happened to be sqlite keyword. I should have paid attention to sql keyword. Now I changed my table name to 'transactions' and it's working now. 
Thankyou.